# visual studio express see events in asp.net source mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is it just me...

I would really like to be able to add/access the events for a control when in the source mode of the GUI, rather than having to switch to design mode.

I know that I can just type in the event, but I do like the convenience of being able to double click the box in the properties window and have the event handler created automatically for me. Plus then I can see all associated properties available for the control.

If there is a setting/option to always show events I have not found it yet, did the community find this toggle?

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Web development, you can use on the page `AutoEventWireup` and adjust to `true`

This functionality associate delegate to event by reflection

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup(v=vs.80).aspx

Nota : you don't need associate event to your delegate